# how to detect event target last child javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function which returns all cell's value of clicked row. But ı don't want it to run when any last cell is clicked.
Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XcsN/282Wy/

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
tbody.onclick = function (e) {
   var data = [];
   var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
   if (target && target.nodeName !== "TR") 
      target = target.parentNode;
   else return;
   var cells = target.getElementsByTagName("td");
   for (var i = 0; i < cells.length - 1; i++) 
        data.push(cells[i].innerHTML);
    alert(target + " " + data);
};
```

target.id or taget.index() does not have value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example use:

### DEMO

```
if($(target).is(':last-child')) return;
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have a new problem. How can I get only last child's value without selcting all children.

Comment: @HakanSONMEZ I'm not sure how is it related to your previous question. Maybe you should ask a new question regarding it.

Comment: I just want to know Can I do same thing one sentence. 
var cells = $(target).children("td");
data = cells[cells.length -1 ].innerHTML;

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery [`.not`](https://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
var onclickEvent = function(){ ... };
$("tbody").not("tbody :last-child").click(onclickEvent);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#lol tbody tr')
        .not(':last')
        .on('click', function(e) {
            var self = $(this);
            console.log(self.find('td').text());
        });
});
```

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/yf5y5/